# Утечки памяти в Android приложении

Tags: android, утечка-памяти

В Android Studio, в панели Memory отображено количество свободной памяти у моего приложения - 2,72MB. Значит ли это, что в моём приложении есть утечки памяти?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это значит, что ваше приложения использует 14.5 МБ памяти. А уж из-за того ли это, что в вашем приложении в памяти хранится много данных, или из-за того, что что-то протекает - вам виднее, так как кода в вопросе нет.

Comment: Спасибо, а что значит Free[2,72MB]?

Comment: Количество оставшейся свободной памяти, я полагаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нет, не значит
2. 14.54 - текущий объем памяти.
3. 2.72 - свободная память в heap вашего приложения.

Что такое heap можно почитать [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html), или где угодно в гугле по запросу [java heap](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20heap&es_th=1)

Кратко: каждое приложение запускается в виртуальной машине Java (длоя Android это Dalvik или ART). При запуске каждому приложению выделяется определенное стандартное кол-во памяти (начальный размер heap). По мере того, как приложению нужно больше памяти для работы, размер heap расширяется (выделяется больше памяти). И расширяется он с неким запасом.
В вашем случае: текущий размер heap = 17.26 mb. Из них свободно 2.72. Как только понадобится больше, будет выделено еще.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение: сперва вызывается сборщик мусора и уже потом, если нужно, выделяется доп.память